# Microsoft PEX gives up the error out message Path Bounds Exceeded

Tags: c#, pex

While running Pex on DAL layer in web application, Pex is getting error out message Path Bounds Exceeded.

Please advise me proceed with this exception and explain the procedure to execute PEX on DAL layer:

```
public DataSet GetEmployeeDetails(int EmpId)
{
      DataSet ds = null;
      try
      {
           DbCommand cmd = null;
           ds = new DataSet();
           cmd = db_dataBase.GetStoredProcCommand("sp_name");
           db_dataBase.AddInParameter(cmd, "@EmpId", DbType.Int32, EmpId);
           ds = db_dataBase.ExecuteDataSet(cmd);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
            throw ex;
        }
       return ds;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pex use runtime instrumentation to generate input to achieve high code coverage.Pex is able to generate input if code under test uses simple logic or .net primitive type.Pex is not suitable for testing DAL layer.You have to hide it behind interface.

Use dependancy injection and repository pattern to remove dependancy.